# How long is a gem5 build with "gem5 scons build/ARM/gem5.opt -j2" expected to take on a docker container?

Tags: python, docker, simulator, scons, gem5

I need to simulate a cpu with an arm ISA and I followed the instructions on https://www.gem5.org/documentation/general_docs/building to build gem5 on a docker container. I'm on an m1 Mac and I have been waiting for a couple of hours. It is still building and I don't have only one other background app running. Is there anything I can do to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

The first time you compile gem5, it is known that it will take several hours (the resulting binaries can be several hundreds of megabytes in size). After this, scons is clever about only recompiling source binaries whose source has been modified, and the source files who reference the modified source. This significantly reduces the time it takes to re-compile in the average case, but still means that modifying highly referred objects (like the Packet class) can result in long compile times.